# Undefined token while compiling Bison/Flex files

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

I'm getting started with Bison/YACC and Flex/Lex, but I cannot compile the simplest of parsers.

File: Ruby.y

```
%{ 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
%}

%start program
%token NUMBER

%%

program : NUMBER;

%%

main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    yyparse();
} 

yyerror(char *s){
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

File: Ruby.l

```
%{
#define "Ruby.tab.h"
%}
DIGIT   [0-9]
%%
{DIGIT}+    { return(NUMBER);           }
[ \t\n]+
.           { return(yytext[0]);        }
%%
```

I compiled Ruby.y using "Bison -vd Ruby.y", then "Flex Ruby.l" and then tried to compile the whole thing using GCC with "GCC -c Ruby.tab.c" and "GCC -c lex.yy.c" but I get the following error on the latter:

Ruby.l:2:9: error: macro names must be identifiers
Ruby.l: In function 'yylex':
Ruby.l:6:10: error: 'NUMBER' undeclared (first use in this function)
Ruby.l:6:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each fun
ction it appears in

I am clueless, any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Ruby.l file this:

```
%{
#define "Ruby.tab.h"
%}
```

should be:

```
%{
#include "Ruby.tab.h"
%}
```

Comment: God, I feel so incredibly dumb! Can't believe I missed that! I've been reading samples and manuals and I used a define instead of an include! *slaps forhead* Thanks!